# Calculating Conditional Probabilities for Categorical and Continuous variables in python? P(categorical|continuous)

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, classification, probability

I have a dataset that has one categorical and multiple continuous variables as follows:

```
A     B     C
2.0  1.0   foo
2.2  1.2   bar
1.0  1.5   foo
```

I wish to compute:

```
Pr(C='foo'| A=2.0) # column A
Pr(C='foo'| A=1.0) # column A
Pr(C='bar'| A=2.2) # column A
Pr(C='foo'| B=1.0) # column B
Pr(C='bar'| B=1.2) # column B
```

What will be an correct approach to solving this? Will it be valid to group the values in A and B into brackets or to compute for every random variable in A and B? Thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate on the results you want to get. In the probalities you want to get you are mixing values and column names. In your example what is the result of Pr(foo|A)?

Comment: @Julian_W, thanks for the clarification. I just edited the question. I am not sure my sample is a correct way to go about it. But the high level explanation of what I am looking for is to compute conditional probabilities of this form Pr(category|continuous). Any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: This is a classification problem. You can use any classification model which produces the posterior probability of the class given the inputs; many ordinary classification such as logistic regression and its generalizations (quadratic discriminant, neural network), produce posterior class probabilities, but some do not (SVM, some tree-structured models). The answers given below give a particular way of computing class probabilities, and that's great, but there are many other methods. Maybe you can say more about your goals or the larger problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @RobertDodier thanks..I have two datasets that are similar. in my analysis towards solving the classification problem. I wish to understand how related (or unrelated) the conditional probabilities (categorical feature) of both datasets are?

Comment: It's not clear what you wish to do, but something that might be helpful: construct distributions p(A, B | C = foo) and p(A, B | C = bar) and plot them to get a feeling for how the foo's and bar's differ. A simple, widely applicable approximation is to assume that p(A, B | C) is a Gaussian distribution. That is, separate the foo's from the bar's and construct a Gaussian bump for each one.

Comment: @Notabie1 See my extended answer, hope this answers your query

Answer (score 3):

1. **A, B are numeric variables, computing conditional probabilities only from the table (considering it as the population)**

Let us assume that A,B can have values from those in the provided table only and take the following example probability table with a few more rows (for better understanding):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('prob.txt', sep=' ') # let the dataframe df store the probability table 
df

# the probability table 
     A   B   C
0   2.0 1.0 foo
1   2.2 1.2 bar
2   1.0 1.5 foo
3   2.0 3.0 bar
4   2.0 2.0 foo
5   3.2 1.2 foo
```

Now, recall the definition of conditional probability, for two events X, Y, with P(Y) != 0:

[image]

Hence, we have

```
# Pr(C='foo'| A=2.0) = Pr(C='foo' & A=2.0) / Pr(A=2.0)

df[(df.C=='foo') & (df.A==2.0)] # Pr(C='foo' & A=2.0), we have 2 such rows
#    A   B   C
# 0 2.0 1.0 foo
# 4 2.0 2.0 foo

df[(df.A==2.0)]    # Pr(A=2.0), we have 3 such rows 
#    A   B   C
# 0 2.0 1.0 foo
# 3 2.0 3.0 bar
# 4 2.0 2.0 foo

# the required probability Pr(C='foo'| A=2.0)
df[(df.C=='foo') & (df.A==2.0)].shape[0] / df[(df.A==2.0)].shape[0]  # 2 / 3
# 0.6666666666666666
```

Likewise we can compute other conditional probabilities too.

2. **Fit a classifier considering the table as a sample training dataset with A,B (continuous) predictor variables, to predict Pr(C|A,B)**

Now let us assume that the table provides a few (randomly) sampled values of the continuous variables A,B from the population and you want to fit a classifier to predict the probability of the class C ('foo'or 'bar'), given the data (with seen / unseen values of the variables A, B), In this case, you can fit any classifier from the library `scikit-learn`, you don't have to implement on your own. For example, the simplest one in this case one can think of is `Naive Bayesian`, although it assumes conditional independence given the class (P(A,B|C) = P(A|C)P(B|C)).

Assuming that you have the dataset df which looks like the following (where i generated the dataset synthetically, you can use your own dataset here)

```
import pandas as pd
# load your data in dataframe df here
df.head()
#        A         B      C
# 0.161729  0.814335    foo
# 0.862661  0.517964    foo
# 0.814303  0.337391    foo
# 1.898132  1.530963    bar
# 2.124829  0.289176    bar

from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
clf = GaussianNB()
X, y = df[['A','B']], df['C']

# fit the classifier on the training dataset
clf.fit(X, y)

# predict the Pr(C = 'bar' | A, B) with predict_proba() 
print(clf.predict_proba([[1,1]])[:,0])   # Pr(C='bar'|A=1.0, B=1.0)
# [ 0.86871233]

import matplotlib.pylab as plt
X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(X[['A']].min(), X[['A']].max(),10), np.linspace(X[['B']].min(), X[['B']].max(),10))
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
# plot the probability surface
plt.contourf(X1, X2, clf.predict_proba(np.c_[X1.ravel(), X2.ravel()])[:,0].reshape(X1.shape), cmap='jet', alpha=.8)
plt.colorbar()
cols = {'foo':'green', 'bar':'red'}
plt.scatter(X[['A']], X[['B']], c=[cols[c] for c in y.tolist()], s=50)
plt.show()
```

The colorbar shows how the probability that C='bar' given the values of A and B (x, y axis in the plot) varies. The original data points are also plotted with green and red color points (with class 'foo' and 'bar' respectively).

[image]

If conditional independence is too strong assumption for you, you can try to fit

- Bayesian classifer: Linear/Quadratic Discriminant Analysis classifier (assume two Gaussians one for Pr(A,B|C='foo') another for Pr(A,B|C='bar') with same / diferent covariance matrix and learn the gaussian parameters for the class-conditional probabilities from the data with MLE/MAP and then compute the posterior probability P(C|A,B) with Bayes theorem, for 1D Gaussian parameter MLE computation [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTcuKnBfN6E) video may be useful). The following figure shows the Gaussians fitted on the class conditional distributions with MLE and the decision surface with LDA classifier.

[image]

[image]

```
clf.predict_proba([[1,1]])[:,0]  # Pr(C='bar'|A=1.0, B=1.0)
# [ 0.67028318]
```

- SVM, RandomForest, NeuralNet for more sophisticated classifiers and predict the probability with the fitted classifier. The following figure shows the decision surface with `RandomForest classifier`.

[image]

```
clf.predict_proba([[1,1]])[:,0]  # Pr(C='bar'|A=1.0, B=1.0)
# [ 1.0]
```

Hope this now answers your question properly.

Comment: This isn't a good solution, because it treats A and B as discrete variables, but OP said A and B are continuous.

Comment: @Robert Dodier I think by continuous OP actually meant to say not categorical. Probability at a particular point is going to be 0 (e.g., P(A=2.0)=0) for a continuous distribution and we can't have probability table at discrete values of the r.v. (it should have been specified by a pdf with ranges of values of the r.v. in that case), hence my assumption was A,B discrete variables.

Comment: There isn't any problem that I can see here; conditional densities are well-defined and commonly used. Don't we want a result which is defined for all values of A and B? Counting discrete values means that the result is undefined at any value not in the the data.

Comment: @Robert Dodier OP did not mention earlier that he wants to find the conditional probabilities because he wants to classify the dataset, now I added the relevant answer

Comment: @SandipanDey thanks a lot for the elaborate answer. please correct me if I am wrong, but predict_proba computes the predicted not actual probabilities of the classes?

Comment: @Notable1 yes it's the predicted probabilites by the model fitted. If you want to know the actual probabilites (from the data from the table only) you can use approach 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think is easier to solve this if you apply the basic probability concept so:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a=np.random.choice([1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4],10)
b=np.random.choice([1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4],10)
c=np.random.choice(['bar','foo'],10)

df=pd.DataFrame({'A':a,'B':b,'C':c})

probs={}
for col in ['A','B']:
    for num in df[col].unique():
        for cat in df['C'].unique():
            tdf=df[df[col]==num]
            N=len(tdf) #total 
            n=len(tdf[tdf['C']==cat]) #occurences
            probs['C:{2}//{0}:{1}'.format(col,num,cat)]=(n/N)
```

returning

```
{'C:bar//A:1.4': 0.6666666666666666,
 'C:foo//A:1.4': 0.3333333333333333,
 'C:bar//A:1.3': 0.6666666666666666,
 'C:foo//A:1.3': 0.3333333333333333,
 'C:bar//A:1.1': 0.0,
 'C:foo//A:1.1': 1.0,
 'C:bar//A:1.2': 0.6666666666666666,
 'C:foo//A:1.2': 0.3333333333333333,
 'C:bar//B:1.3': 0.6666666666666666,
 'C:foo//B:1.3': 0.3333333333333333,
 'C:bar//B:1.4': 0.5,
 'C:foo//B:1.4': 0.5,
 'C:bar//B:1.2': 0.6666666666666666,
 'C:foo//B:1.2': 0.3333333333333333}
```

with this generated data frame

```
     A   B   C
0   1.4 1.3 bar
1   1.3 1.4 bar
2   1.1 1.2 foo
3   1.4 1.4 foo
4   1.2 1.3 bar
5   1.2 1.4 foo
6   1.3 1.3 foo
7   1.4 1.2 bar
8   1.3 1.4 bar
9   1.2 1.2 bar
```

Comment: I don't know if this is a workable solution, since it treats A and B as discrete variables, but OP said A and B are continuous.